# SDL2 fails to create GL context when program is run in Monodevelop, works fine otherwise

Tags: c#, opengl, sdl, monodevelop, opentk

I have a very unusual problem. I have this OpenTK project (which I've last worked on a few months ago on a different Linux machine, back then everything worked fine).

My project compiles just fine and when I run the executable myself from the terminal everything works perfectly - the window is created and so on.

However, when I run the exact same program from within Monodevelop by hitting the Run key (with or without debugging enabled), an exception is thrown because of the following SDL2 error : `"Could not create GL context: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)"`

I've already tried just about anything, from changing the context creation parameters, to changing OpenTK versions, but nothing has helped at all. OpenTK's output (before the SDL2 error occurs is :

```
Creating GraphicsContext.
    GraphicsMode: Index: , Color: 32 (8888), Depth: 16, Stencil: 0, Samples: 0, Accum: 0 (0000), Buffers: 2, Stereo: False
    IWindowInfo: OpenTK.Platform.SDL2.Sdl2WindowInfo
    GraphicsContextFlags: Default
    Requested version: 3.2
```

These parameters are the same, whether I run the program manually or from Monodevelop. So I guess my question is - what could possibly be the difference between starting the program manually and running it in Monodevelop, which causes this error to happen?

(This is happening on Ubuntu 16 with Monodevelop 6, OpenTK 1.1 (also 2.0) and SDL 2.0.4)

Comment: Could it be that you run e.g. 32bit version mono, or just different version? Make your process stall (sleep, blocking call, interrupt by debugger) and check where /proc/<process_id>/exe points to, for both versions.

Comment: The monodevelop process is running "/app/bin/mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=xxx /path/to/executable.exe", when I just run the executable myself, the process's path is simply "mono path/to/executable.exe". /app/bin/mono does not exist though...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I more or less solved my problem. As is strongly recommended on Monodevelop's website, I had installed it with flatpak, which runs in some kind of sandbox that probably had issues with SDL. I re-installed Monodevelop the normal way and now everything is working as it should.